# GL_DEPTH_TEST not working

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

## Problem

I have a problem with Depth Test on GLES20. It simply not working. The symptoms are as follows:
When I try to render 2 points: `NEAR = (0,0,-0.3)` and `FAR = (0,0,-0.8)`, I get wrong results - I always see the point, which was rendered second. I.e., when I make my rendering calls (1):

```
drawBlueNear(300.0f); // draws blue point (0,0,-0.3,1.0) with size 300
drawRedFar(500.0f);   // draws red point (0,0,-0.8,1.0) with size 500
```

I get different result, than when I make calls (2):

```
drawRedFar(500.0f);
drawBlueNear(300.0f);
```

**Thus, it seems that the Depth Test fails.**
Picture for calls (1):
[image]

Picture for calls (2):
[image]

## Code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView mGLSurfaceView;
    private DepthTestRenderer mRenderer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mGLSurfaceView = new GLSurfaceView(this);
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);
        mGLSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(true);
        mRenderer = new DepthTestRenderer(this);
        mGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(mRenderer);
        setContentView(mGLSurfaceView);
    }

}
```

```
public class DepthTestRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.9f, 0.6f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_LEQUAL);
        GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
        GLES20.glDepthRangef(0.0f, -1.0f);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        drawRedFar(500.0f);
        drawBlueNear(300.0f);

//      drawBlueNear(300.0f);
//      drawRedFar(500.0f);

    }

}
```

## Peculiarity

Moreover, I have checked following configuration:

```
public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.2f, 0.9f, 0.6f, 1.0f);
        GLES20.glClearDepthf(-0.3f);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        GLES20.glDepthFunc(GLES20.GL_EQUAL);
        GLES20.glDepthMask(true);
    }

public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {

        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        drawRedFar(500.0f);
        drawBlueNear(300.0f);

    }
```

What is strange, I got the same view on screen, that in in the picture (1), **thus it seems, that both my points have depth equal to 0.3f**, but I'm pretty sure it shouldn't be this way: The way I'm rendering points is that I assign uniform value to shader program.

**Do You have any idea, what could be the problem and how to solve it?**

**EDIT:**
With reference to comments, I'm adding shaders and draw methods code. My perspective properties are default, I have not used any MVP matrix here. Therefore near plane is 0.0f and far plane is -1.0f.

```
private float mCoorNear = -0.3f;
private float mCoorFar = -0.8f;

private void drawBlueNear(float size) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    GLES20.glUniform1f(h_u_size, size);
    GLES20.glUniform3f(h_u_point, 0.0f, 0.0f, mCoorNear);
    GLES20.glUniform3f(h_u_color, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
}

private void drawRedFar(float size) {
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

    GLES20.glUniform1f(h_u_size, size);
    GLES20.glUniform3f(h_u_point, 0.0f, 0.0f, mCoorFar);
    GLES20.glUniform3f(h_u_color, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
uniform vec3 u_point;
uniform float u_size;

void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(u_point, 1.0);
    gl_PointSize = u_size;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform vec3 u_color;

void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(u_color, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: How are your shaders defined? How is drawRedFar or drawBlueNear defined?

Comment: Where is your projection set up? Are you using an orthographic or perspective projection? Either way, what are the near and far clipping plane distances set to?

Comment: @PasiMatalamäki I've added methods and shaders code to the question

Comment: @wcochran I have default perspective setting, therefore near plane is 0.0f and far plane -1.0f. Added disambiguation to question.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by default perspective projection... By default the identity matrix would be used which is a simple orthographic projection. If you truly are using a perspective projection with the near plane set to zero then depth sorting will not work,

Comment: @wcochran Actually yes, I have used identity matrix. However, I have calculated MVP matrix from `GLES20.perspectiveM()` and set `zNear=0.01f` and `zFar=10f`. Depth test is still not working (ofc, I have added MVP matrix to vertex shader).